# How to get selected values from Dynamic-Autocomplete-Multi-select in php(server side)?

Tags: php, jquery

The below mentioned plugin is used.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Dynamic-Autocomplete-Multi-select-Plugin-With-jQuery-magicsearch.html

Here is the code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(function() {
            var dataSource = [
                <?php foreach ($candidate_list as $row_candidate) { ?>
                {id: <?=$row_candidate->candidate_id?>, firstName: '<?=$row_candidate->first_name?>', lastName: '<?=$row_candidate->last_name?>'},

                <?php } ?>
            ];
            $('#interview_candidates').magicsearch({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                fields: ['firstName', 'lastName'],
                id: 'id',
                method:'POST',
                format: '%firstName%  %lastName%',
                multiple: true,
                focusShow: true,
                multiField: 'firstName',
                multiStyle: {
                    space: 5,
                    width: 80
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

How to get selected values of dropdown list in server side(PHP)

Answer (score 0):

As (not really) stated by the plugin's documentation :

> 3. Inert an input field into the webpage where needed.

```
<input class="magicsearch" id="basic" placeholder="search names...">
```

http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Dynamic-Autocomplete-Multi-select-Plugin-With-jQuery-magicsearch.html

The input field is the actual receiver of the component data. It should have a `name="Something"` attribute for you to be able to submit it through a regular html form and catch the value with php as a standard GET or POST variable, depending on the form settings.

Comment: <input type="text"  id="interview_candidates" name="interview_candidates[]" placeholder="Select Candidates" multiple="multiple" class="magicsearch form-control" value="">

I have added above code in webpage but it no receiving in server side

server side code

print_r(explode(',',$_POST['interview_candidates']));

Comment: @Suhaskn have you added it __inside__ of the <form> you are trying to submit ? what exactly happens with the print_r() line above ? and why did you append array brackets to the name ([]) ? that would break the explode() for sure.

Answer (score 0):

it should be just a normal form. Give a `name` attribute to your input in a form tag and get the value from `$_POST` in php.

Example:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['name'])){ echo $_POST['name']; }
?>

<form method='post'> <input type='text' name='name' > <button type='submit'>Submit</button> </form>
```

in case you got comma separated values then you can `explode` the string by comma, like:

```
<?php print_r(explode(',',$_POST['name']);
```

Comment: I tried like this bit it is not working.    
<input type="text" id="interview_candidates" name="interview_candidates[]" placeholder="Select Candidates" multiple="multiple" class="magicsearch form-control" value=""> I have added above code in webpage but it no receiving in server side server side code print_r(explode(',',$_POST['interview_candidates']));

Comment: if you are using chrome, check your network tab and see what form values are posting. Here's is the reference how to check that. 

http://www.exegetic.biz/blog/2016/09/viewing-post-data/

Answer (score 0):

In the setup of the magic search,  add the name attribute. Like:

```
name: 'name'
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using this, and from http://www.choujindeputao.com/magicsearch/  (i only read english part)

Just add data-id='value1, value2' on your input (exchange of value)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a hack job, but here's how I got it to work for me.

1. Use the option to generate a hidden input

   hidden: false,
2. Modify the jquery.magicsearch.js script

Look for:

```
var f=a.attr("name"),g=t('<input class="'+l.hidden+'" type="hidden" value="'+n+'">');
```

I added name="magicreturn" to it so it now looks like:

```
var f=a.attr("name"),g=t('<input class="'+l.hidden+'" type="hidden" name="magicreturn" value="'+n+'">');
```

3. You can now find the values of all the selected items using the $_POST['magicreturn']

Hopefully that helps, or hopefully someone can come up with a better way.